# How do you execute a JavaScript function when the page has fully rendered?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, prototypejs

How would you go about executing a JavaScript function when the page is fully rendered (Displayed) I know that the `onLoad` event executes when the page is loaded but Before it's rendered.

I've previously solved this problem by using a timeout with a 0 interval, which seems to work usually, but seems a little inelegant to my delicate sensibilities.

Is there a proper way to do this?

I'm using prototype as my JavaScript framework so answers that involve that are helpful, however I would have thought that this would be built into JavaScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The onload event fires when the page is fully rendered (including dependancies such as images).

Perhaps you are confusing it with Prototype's [dom:loaded event](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/document/observe) (which fires when the DOM is loaded but before all the dependancies have been included)?

(To be honest, this sounds like [an X-Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).)