# JavaScript doesn't work until I resize the window then resize it back

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've implemented JavaScript on wordpress and it only works after i re-size the window from the original size to a different size then back to the original size. I don't understand why it just doesn't work from the start?

Here is the script in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/dw-minion/assets/css/jstick/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/dw-minion/assets/css/jstick/jquery.stickem.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.container').stickem();
  });
</script>
```

The place the script is used in content.php inside the body

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row stickem-container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="entry-content"> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_content(); ?></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aside stickem">
      <div class="sharepinterest">
        <?php echo get_simple_local_avatar( $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the resize function?

Comment: do i need one or do i have it somewhere?

Comment: You said the function is triggered when you resize the window. So I am wondering where the function is that handles the resize.

Comment: where should it be? i don't want it to be like that its just doing that

Answer (score 0):

Scripts should be enqueued for execution using `wp_enqueue_script` in `functions.php` file of your theme. This is the preferred method to enqueue scripts and style.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Perhaps this might be preventing your script from being executed right from start.

Comment: it is possible to do this without that though

Answer (score 0):

Would prefer to comment but don't have the reputation, please check here.

[Running javascript after page is fully rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611713/running-javascript-after-page-is-fully-rendered)

I had this issue prevsiouly as a script was being triggered before the page was rendered. Resizing the window, zooming in and out and also bringing up the chrome element inspector reszied the issue div.