# run js function after all scripts on page are fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jinja2

I am trying to run a simple javascript function when my page is completely loaded. For example, this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeSize() {
  var el = document.getElementById("my-id");
  el.style.height = "500px";
  };
</script>
```

My page has a long-loading (seconds) script retrieved from an external URL that renders the main content in the html body.

I am using Bootstrap where the body section of my `base.html` is:

```
<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    {% block header %}{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}{% endblock %}

  </div>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

The content block is loaded via an external html file, which is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header %}
{% include 'header.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="my-class" id="my-id">
        {{ myapp | safe }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

In the `'my-id'` element, `myapp` is rendered via the long-loading js script that, when finished, renders all the content of the page. The external URL route for `myapp` is retrieved and defined by a python script using Flask.

I have tried `window.onload = changeSize;`, `<body onload="changeSize();">`, and I have checked the timing of all stages of `document.readyState`.

These all trigger my js function when the html is fully loaded, but before the external script for `myapp` is complete. How do I detect when all elements and scripts are completely done loading?

Comment: Where is you script tag? You script should be executed after the external sources.

Comment: There is no specific script tag in the html for the long-loading script. It is only called via `myapp` in the content block. I can identify the script using the DevTools Network tab as a script that starts with `autoload.js?...`. It continues to load after all other elements are complete.

Comment: Can you change "`myapp`" or the script it loads? Add a callback feature to notify your page that it is complete.  An example is google maps api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>` where `initMap` is a function on your page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution using a delay method (adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980425/4306938) SO answer).

Put the following in a `custom.js` file:

```
function delay() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        changeSize();
    }, 200);
}

if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
    delay();
} else {
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            delay();
        }
    }
}
```

Then load the `custom.js` in `base.html` with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='custom.js') }}"></script>
```

This successfully waits until the long-loading script and related content is fully rendered, then executes the `changeSize()` function.

Comment: You can do this with a duration of `0` or `setTimeout(function(){ ... },0)` if you're just looking to push the running of the function to the back of the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). No need to add the extra 200 ms.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how the external scripts are loaded. If they loaded using a special library, you need to wait for callback and afterward call your App initialization.

But you can take a look at `DOMContentLoaded` event. It also could help, If I'm right.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});
```

Comment: The DOM is full loaded and parsed before the long-running script finishes.

Comment: The **DOMContentLoaded** event fires when the HTML document has been completely parsed, and all deferred scripts (```<script defer src="…">``` and ```<script type="module">```) have downloaded and executed. It doesn't wait for other things like images, subframes, and async scripts to finish loading.
see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event