# Event Listener for DomComplete event not executing

Tags: javascript, html

I added an event listener to execute after the dom is complete, but it does not seem to execute. Why?

I am deferring a number of javascript tags and need my event to execute after them.

```
document.addEventListener('domComplete', function () {
  console.log('domcomplete');
});
```

Comment: Try `DOMContentLoaded` [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: Does not work, as the libraries do not get loaded completely before the event executes.  domContentLoaded: marks the point when both the DOM is ready and there are no stylesheets that are blocking JavaScript execution - meaning we can now (potentially) construct the render tree. It does not wait for all the JS to finish loading when using 'defer'

Comment: [domComplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/domComplete) is not an event but a read-only property that happens to be deprecated. Anyway, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046523/run-js-function-after-all-scripts-on-page-are-fully-loaded) help?

Comment: I just read that "DOMContentLoaded waits for the deferred script", so I am reading conflcting info. I do know that if I do not defer my script, DomContentLoaded works, but I need to defer.

Comment: Just put your scripts in the order you want them executed [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts)

Comment: I thought of that, but from an organizational stand point, I like have the event listeners in the same spot as the helpers they relate to, so at the bottom of any  helper, I initialize the object using the even listener. Otherwse I need to make a completely different script with all my  initializes of my helpers and load it in with another script tag call, slowing page loads.