# Display HTML content once the layout phase is complete

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, delay, preloader

I'd like to display content once everything is available and correctly positioned in the web page. Most preloader techniques only consider download time, not rendering time, therefore letting the user seeing the page being constructed. That's short, but clearly noticeable. I'm using WebKit inside a native app, but that shouldn't matter.

**What is the correct approach to delay content display until the page is completely ready?**

Comment: hide the body using visibility:hidden, then unhide with js onready/load(). you can put a style to un-hind it inside a noscript block to service non-js browsers.

Comment: @dandavis, it would be better to put your more explained solution as an answer.

Comment: That's the classic preloader technique I'm talking about: `$.ready()` will happen before the layout is done. I can achieve what I want with a `setTimeout`, but I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you execute a Javascript function when the page has fully rendered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939538/how-do-you-execute-a-javascript-function-when-the-page-has-fully-rendered)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned above, you can initially style everything to be [`visibility:hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

```
<div id="content" style="visibility:hidden">
   <!-- all your content 
        (won't be displayed, as long as they are not explicitly
         visibility:visible) -->
</div>
```

The javascript to un-hide everything is quite simple:

```
function unhide() { document.getElementById("content").style.visibility = ""; }
```

To call it when *everything* is loaded, use the `load` event:

```
document.addEventListener('load', unhide, false);
```

I think the jQuery [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler actually listens to the `DOMContentLoaded` event in modern browsers, so it'll run before your images are loaded. If you only need the layout fixed before displaying everything, you can use `ready()` or `DOMContentLoaded`, but be sure to explicitly specify the image dimensions in HTML.